# phonegap for android development using eclipse

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to android development. Although i have done some development using eclipse (java and xml) but would like to know something to get started for phonegap.

Comment: see here http://docs.phonegap.com

Comment: are you using windows system ?

Answer (score 1):

Check these below links :

[Getting Started with Phone Gap for Android (1)](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/set-up-an-environment-for-android-eclipse-and-phonegap/)

and

[Getting Started with Phone Gap for Android (2)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide to start developing with PhoneGap 3 for Android on a Windows machine.You need the following platforms / software packages.this is a tutorial to start phoneGap development .[use this](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html)